# $wpdb->get_results in not an array

Tags: wpdb, array, php

Using get_result I receive an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" because is not an array. I tried with get_col but I don't know how to extract the data and I don't know the difference between them.

can someone suggest me how to fix this problem?

```
function vendorDatails( $param)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id  FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission  WHERE order_id = %d";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query,   intval($param) );


            foreach ($result as $row)
                {
                    echo $row->vendor_id . '<br/>';
                }

    //clean all results
    $wpdb->flush();
}
```

Comment: Try this: `$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );`

Comment: thanks, the warning is disappeared. Now the echo, inside the foreach, doesn't show anything. What could be the problem?

Comment: Then I think $result doesn't have any data. What do you see if you use `echo "<pre>";print_r($result); echo "</pre>";` ? Do you see anything printed?

Comment: Ahh I see this. Your query is `"SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id  FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission  WHERE order_id = %d";` but you need to use sprintf and/or prepare statement to change %d to something integer. Maybe like this: `sprintf('SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id  FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission  WHERE order_id = %d', 12)`

Comment: I have to use sprintf like an alternative of get_results?

Comment: if I use this code is better? <code>$query = "SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id  FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission  WHERE order_id = $param";
  
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );</code>

Comment: Well, try this: http://pastebin.com/FN4xk9BW Make sure you change the value 12 to something appropriate.

Comment: What is $param here? Is $param an order_id? If yes, then this: `$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id  FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission  WHERE order_id = %d", $param);`

Comment: Yes is an order_id. I tried but no error and no result printed

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/TTWd8SxU

Comment: with last code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: My bad! A semicolon was missing. http://pastebin.com/direT6Y2

Comment: thanks for your correction but no result showed

Comment: the query string is correct beacause if I use this in mysql workbench I have 2 result

Comment: I tested the foreach with another echo to print something but  none was printed. Is there an alternative to foreach for print the result?